# Restore Bluestacks Backup

Tags: backup, windows, bluestacks

I receive the following message after backing up (while signed in) and restoring (again, while signed in) data in Bluestacks: the bluestacks account associated with this backup is different than current signed in account.

I need help solving this, I have no other account than this.